# typescript monorepo single package strict mode - gradual adoption

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsc, monorepo

I have a few monorepo packages - each with typescript strict mode disabled.
I would like to adapt it into 2 packages (for now).

Packages have circular dependencies (package A installs B and package B installs A). I tried https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html but it requires no circular dependencies.
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33685

Expected behaviour: I would like to have typescript strict mode enabled in one package and for others, should be disabled. This behaviour should not only work in IDE but also when running the `tsc` command. Solution can be slow

Thanks